# Error Keyerror 255 when executing pymysql.connect

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Here is the code

```
import pymysql
pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    password='iDontWannaSay',
    db='iDontWannaShow',
    charset='utf8'
)
```

and the error Traceback was:

```
data is :::::b'\xff\x02\x00\xff\x81\x15'....##### I was add near line 1279 which is print("data is :::::%s...."%data[i:i+6])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\123\Desktop\pymysqldebug.py", line 8, in <module>
    charset='utf8'
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 709, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 934, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1279, in _get_server_information
    self.server_charset = charset_by_id(lang).name
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\charset.py", line 39, in by_id
    return self._by_id[id]
KeyError: 255
```

seems like struct.unpack method parse '\xff\' to 255 and assigned to `self.server_language`, whatever the non-null charset argument passed.

Is this an MySQL version problem?(version `8.0.1-dmr`)

Answer (score 17):

To extend the above link-only accepted answer, consider the following changes on your current `pymysql` install. With MySQL 8, the mysql-python API does not recognize possibly newer character sets and hence the raised `KeyError`.

To resolve, locate the *connectors.py* script under the `pymysql` module found at this directory:

```
print(pymysql.__file__)
```

Backup orginal *connectors.py* script. Then incorporate the following changes.

**Original** *(lines 1268-1269)*

```
self.server_language = lang
self.server_charset = charset_by_id(lang).name
```

**Replace** *(lines 1268 - 1272)*

```
self.server_language = lang
try:
    self.server_charset = charset_by_id(lang).name
except KeyError:
    self.server_charset = None
```

Be careful to include hidden tabs in indentation with above lines.

**Reference**

- [PyMySQL Git fix #591](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/commit/4b7e9c98c0441449352d732f6a2453e4c868505c?diff=split)

Comment: As mentioned above, we can upgrade the pymysql module.
`pip install --upgrade pymysql`

Comment: Running upgrade pymysql did it for me without having to manually change anything.

Comment: Good to know @mothmonsterman. Please note this answer is over three years old. Likely `pymysql` fixed it by now!

Answer (score -1):

but where's your variable?

```
import pymysql

    |
    v
myVariable = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    password='iDontWannaSay',
    db='iDontWannaShow',
    charset='utf8'
)
```

Comment: variable is needed but doesn't make it get the charset,
I located the line 38 at charset.py and return an interger index of self.by_id to avoid it

Comment: @PayneWaston ... can you kindly write an answer to what you **exactly** did. Neither this comment or above or even Git links clearly show how problem is resolved.

Comment: Incorrect answer, Please add this as comment to original question.