# Not able to execute read_sql_table in pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I am new to python and trying to use sqlalchemy statements for e.g read_sql_table.

I am using pycharm to execute below code.

When I am executing below code its not giving me any error :

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:*****@localhost:3306/STAGING')

print("BLAH")
```

OUTPUT:

```
BLAH
```

But when I am trying to execute below statement its giving me error

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:*****@localhost:3306/STAGING')

print("BLAH")
df = pd.read_sql_table("customers",engine)
```

ERROR:

```
BLAH Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 950, in _do_get
    return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\queue.py", line 145, in get
    raise Empty sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/suksengupta/PycharmProjects/Project_July2019/DB.py", line 6, in <module>
    df = pd.read_sql_table("customers",engine)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 243, in read_sql_table
    meta.reflect(only=[table_name], views=True)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3311, in reflect
    with bind.connect() as conn:   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1778, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.__connection = connection or engine.raw_connection()   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1847, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.unique_connection()   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 280, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 644, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 440, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 963, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 285, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 411, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__connect()   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 538, in __connect
    connection = self.__pool._creator()   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 90, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 377, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 88, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 644, in __init__
    self._connect()   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 837, in _connect
    self._get_server_information()   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1072, in _get_server_information
    self.server_charset = charset_by_id(lang).name   File "C:\Users\suksengupta\PycharmProjects\Project_July2019\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\charset.py", line 34, in by_id
    return self._by_id[id] KeyError: 255
```

In output I am expecting all the data present under Customers table

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you have an up-to-date version of pymysql? If not, you might try a `pip install --upgrade pymysql`. Your error message seems very similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368336/error-keyerror-255-when-executing-pymysql-connect) referencing a bug fixed in [PyMySQL PR 591](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/pull/591) with the addition of some new charset definitions.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I checked pymysql is upto date in my system:

pip3 install --upgrade pymysql
Requirement already up-to-date: pymysql in c:\users\suksengupta\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.9.3)

I tried updating connections.py file but still no luck .:( ...

Comment: ok. So I updated connections.py file as mentioned in Github link. And now below code is executing fine
db = pymysql.connect (host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    password='Admin123',
    db='STAGING',
    charset='utf8')

cursor = db.cursor()

But Now I am getting new error i.e. pymysql.err.InternalError: (1193, "Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'")
I tried updating the pip install --upgrade SQLAlchemy