# Python PyMySql KeyError: 255 in Azure notebooks

Tags: python, azure, pymysql, keyerror

i get this error when trying to connect to my dB:

```
~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py in Connect(*args, **kwargs)
     88     """
     89     from .connections import Connection
---> 90     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
     91 
     92 from pymysql import connections as _orig_conn

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in __init__(self, host, user, password, database, port, unix_socket, charset, sql_mode, read_default_file, conv, use_unicode, client_flag, cursorclass, init_command, connect_timeout, ssl, read_default_group, compress, named_pipe, no_delay, autocommit, db, passwd, local_infile, max_allowed_packet, defer_connect, auth_plugin_map, read_timeout, write_timeout)
    686             self._sock = None
    687         else:
--> 688             self.connect()
    689 
    690     def _create_ssl_ctx(self, sslp):

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in connect(self, sock)
    903             self._next_seq_id = 0
    904 
--> 905             self._get_server_information()
    906             self._request_authentication()
    907 

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in _get_server_information(self)
   1229             i += 6
   1230             self.server_language = lang
-> 1231             self.server_charset = charset_by_id(lang).name
   1232 
   1233             self.server_status = stat

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/charset.py in by_id(self, id)
     36 
     37     def by_id(self, id):
---> 38         return self._by_id[id]
     39 
     40     def by_name(self, name):

KeyError: 255
```

i have read in this post [Error Keyerror 255 when executing pymysql.connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368336/error-keyerror-255-when-executing-pymysql-connect) that the problem could easily be solved by altering this file `pymysql.__file__`.

But in addition to this file ending at line 143 (insted of 1268 where the exception is thrown) i can only read the file in python but not access it since it is not local. I did not find a way to pip upgrade pymysql either.

EDIT:
i just found a terminal on azure but my permission is being denied. Is there anything i can do?

```
nbuser@nbserver:~$ pip install --upgrade pymysql
Collecting pymysql
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/39/15045ae46f2a123019aa968dfcba0396c161c20f855f11dea6796bcaae95/PyMySQL-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pymysql
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyMySQL-0.9.3.dist-info'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to connect your MySQL database with the default version of `pymysql` from Azure Notebooks, but failed then try to upgrade the `pymysql` version via the terminal in Azure Notebooks.

As I known, you can not directly do the upgrade operation via `pip` in the terminal of Azure Notebooks, the reasons are as below.

1. The Python runtime in a notebook of Azure Notebooks is Anaconda, not the default Python runtime on Linux OS of Azure Notebooks. So directly to run `pip` in terminal is for changing the default python libraries of Linux system in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/`.
2. There is no `root` permission and the `nbuser` password for `nbuser`, so you can not run `pip` successfully in terminal, even with `sudo`.

There are two ways to upgrade the `pymysql` version of `Anaconda3_420`, as below.

1. Directly to run your command in a notebook, as the figure below.

   [image]
2. In the terminal, to move to the `bin` path of Anaconda what the current notebook you used, then to do the upgrade operation as the figure below.

   [image]

For verification `pymysql` to connect to a mysql instance, I created an instance of Azure Database for MySQL servers, the connection string is like `cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="<your mysql user>@<your mysql host>", password={your_password}, host="<your mysql host>.mysql.database.azure.com", port=3306, database={your_database}, ssl_ca={ca-cert filename}, ssl_verify_cert=true)` for using `mysql-connector-python-rf` as Azure offical document [`Quickstart: Use Python to connect and query data with Azure Database for MySQL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-python) said. I disabled the SSL configure to run the code below successfully.

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com',
                             user='xxxx@xxxx',
                             password='xxxxx',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "select 1+1 as result"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
connection.close()
```

[image]